# angular js not waiting for rest response

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am new to angular js. I have to work with the rest calls in java. I have taken an example related to angularjs, java rest.

see app.js

```
angular.module('ngdemo', ['ngRoute','ngdemo.filters', 'ngdemo.services', 'ngdemo.directives', 'ngdemo.controllers']).
        config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/user-list', {templateUrl: 'partials/user-list.html', controller: 'UserListCtrl'});
            $routeProvider.when('/user-detail/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/user-detail.html', controller: 'UserDetailCtrl'});
            $routeProvider.when('/user-creation', {templateUrl: 'partials/user-creation.html', controller: 'UserCreationCtrl'});
        }]);
```

controllers.js

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var app = angular.module('ngdemo.controllers', []);

app.run(function ($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $templateCache.removeAll();
    });
});


app.controller('UserListCtrl', ['$scope', 'UsersFactory', 'UserFactory', 'DeleteUserFactory', 'UsersSearchFactory', '$location',
    function ($scope, UsersFactory, UserFactory, DeleteUserFactory, UsersSearchFactory, $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'editUser':
        $scope.editUser = function (userId) {
            $location.path('/user-detail/' + userId);
        };

        $scope.searchUser = function () {
            $scope.users = UsersSearchFactory.search($scope.user);
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'deleteUser':
        $scope.deleteUser = function (user) {
            DeleteUserFactory.delete(user);
            $scope.users = UsersFactory.query({startRow: 0}, {endRow: 75});
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'createUser':
        $scope.createNewUser = function () {
            $location.path('/user-creation');
        };

        $scope.users = UsersFactory.query({startRow: 0}, {endRow: 75});

    }]);

app.controller('UserDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'UserFactory', 'UpdateUserFactory', '$location',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, UserFactory, UpdateUserFactory, $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'updateUser':
        $scope.updateUser = function () {
            UpdateUserFactory.update($scope.user);
            $location.path('/user-list');
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'cancel':
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $location.path('/user-list');
        };

        $scope.user = UserFactory.show({id: $routeParams.id});
    }]);

app.controller('UserCreationCtrl', ['$scope', 'CreateUserFactory', '$location',
    function ($scope, CreateUserFactory, $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'createNewUser':
        $scope.createNewUser = function () {
            CreateUserFactory.create($scope.user);
            $location.path('/user-list');
        }
    }]);
```

services.js

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

var services = angular.module('ngdemo.services', ['ngResource']);


services.factory('UsersFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/getUsers/:startRow/:endRow', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true, params: {startRow: '@startRow', endRow: '@endRow'}  },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});

services.factory('UsersCountFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/getUsersCount', {}, {
        count: { method: 'GET'}
    })
});

services.factory('UsersSearchFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/searchUser', {}, {
        search: { method: 'POST', isArray: true, }
    })
});

services.factory('CreateUserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/registerUser', {}, {
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});

services.factory('UpdateUserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/updateUser', {}, {
        update: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});

services.factory('DeleteUserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/deleteUser', {}, {
        delete: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});


services.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/ngdemo/rest/findUserById/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET' }
    })
});
```

user-list.html

```
<div class="container">
        <form novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputFirstName">First name:</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputFirstName" ng-model="user.firstName" placeholder="First name"/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <a ng-click="searchUser()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Search</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>

<div class="span6">
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" >
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th style="min-width: 80px;"> First Name</th>
            <th style="min-width: 80px;"> Last Name</th>
            <th style="width:20px;">&nbsp;</th>
            <th style="width:20px;">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users" > <!--  | orderBy:sort.sortingOrder:sort.reverse" > -->
            <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
            <td><a ng-click="editUser(user.userId)" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">edit</a></td>
            <td><a ng-click="deleteUser(user)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a ng-click="createNewUser()" class="btn btn-small">create new user</a>       
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ngdemo">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ngdemo app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#/user-list">user-list</a></li>

</ul>

<div ng-view></div>

<!-- JQuery ================================================================ -->
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap ============================================================= -->
<script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS App Code ==================================================== -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Question:
I am getting the rest call to server and it is sending the response.
When i open index.html it is displaying the out put on the page. When i click on edit(update) or delete buttons or create new user button, the user details are saved in the database but the changed data is not displayed on the table.

This is happened because after editing(updating) , deleting and creating new user the angular code is not waiting for the response from REST call. It immediately calls the             $location.path('/user-list'); So old data is displayed in the table.

Please help me.

Comment: Read the documentation for $resource. Specifially the "Returns" section. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Do i need to add the success responses for all the rest calls in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the success call backs for all the methods update, create, delete as

```
$scope.createNewUser = function () {
            CreateUserFactory.create($scope.user, function(response) {
                $location.path('/user-list');   
            });
        }
```